# In page (hash) link, get to the first visible element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a partial view (handlebars html template) that has a piece for html for desktop and one piece of mobile. I just hide it accordingly using different css classes.

```
<div class='hideOnMobile showOnDesktop'>
  <a name='manuals' href='#'>Manuals</a>
  <!-- Extra html for Desktop presentations -->
</div>
<div class='hideOnDesktop showOnMobile'>
  <a name='manuals' href='#'>Manuals</a>
  <!-- Extra html for Mobile presentations -->
</div>
```

The important pieces of my css is basically hiding and showing the elements using media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) {
   .showOnMobile { display: block; }
   .hideOnMobile { display: none; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
   .showOnDesktop { display: block; }
   .hideOnDesktop { display: none; }
}
```

CSS is attached for reference. The css is actually working as expected. The problem is the following:

When the browser receives the url for that specific page `http://example.org/page.html#manuals`, I would like the document to navigate directly to the **first visible** `<a>` element. No matter what, I cannot make the deep link to work with the first visible element. I've read that there is some kind of limitations, but I wanted to know if there is a work around, or if the only option that I have is to emulate the deep link using `javascript` (that I'm trying to avoid). Thanks a lot

Comment: better you set only one class. Like class="extradiv" and set display:block in css. afterwards set add and remove class in javascript. it works better.

Comment: Sorry I do not quite get this comments, but the objective of my media queries is not not having to write jquery to show and hide elements on mobile devices and having the need of implementing a `resize` on every page... media queries can do it by themselves....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the markup can be altered?

```
<a name='manuals' id="manuals" href='#manuals'>Manuals</a>
<div class='hideOnMobile showOnDesktop'>
  <!-- Extra html for Desktop presentations -->
</div>
<div class='hideOnDesktop showOnMobile'>
  <!-- Extra html for Mobile presentations -->
</div>
```

This way, the target of the hash (#manuals) is always visible regardless of the environment. This also makes it a bit more maintainable since you have less duplication.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer... I've considered html redesign but the structure is not that simple as the example in terms of hierarchy... so I wanted to know if there is a native way to for the # links to navigate to the first visible element ... before any drastic measure